# Send future through stream

Tags: dart, dart-async

I was wondering, is it possible to send a `Future` through a stream that can get resolved after "reception" by a listener?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Futures are just values, so you can make a `Stream<Future>`. The receiver of the future can then wait on the future normally, and you can complete it at any point in between

It's generally frowned upon, though, because of the double asynchrony.

What it does is to make the receiver wait for a stream event, which you emit at one point, then have the receiver wait again for the actual result which may come at an even later point.

The most urgent issue with that is that you don't always know whether the future has been received yet when you complete it. Maybe the receiver paused the stream, maybe you are quicker than you expected. In any case, if you complete the future with an *error* before it has been received, then that error is probably going to end up uncaught, which may crash your entire program.

It also has bad usability. If you instead waited for the future on the sending side and only sent the event when the result was ready, it's easier and simpler for the receiver (they just get the result as normal), and it's usually just as good at achieving what you want to achieve.

If you really have a situation where a number of asynchronous results (futures) can complete in any order, but the receiver needs to know the original order of the futures themselves, then I guess a `Stream<Future<X>>` can be the answer (but do consider whether your solution is just needlessly complicated).

Example (in full generality):

```
Stream<Future<int>> randomDelays() { 
  var controller = StreamController<Future<String>>();
  controller.onListen = () {
    var rng = Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var delay = rng.nextInt(10);
      var completer = Completer<int>();
      controller.add(completer.future);
      Timer(Duration(seconds: delay), () {
        completer.complete(i);
      });
    }
    controller.close();
  }
}
```

or simpler:

```
Future<Stream<int>> randomDelays() async* {
  var rng = Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var delay = rng.nextInt(10);
    yield Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: delay), () => i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your want that but sure you can do that:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  final controller = StreamController<FutureOr<int>>();
  controller.sink.add(Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => 5));
  print(controller.stream.first.runtimeType); // _Future<FutureOr<int>>
}
```

When you add a Future to the sink it will not be automatically awaited. So what you get out from the Stream are Future objects if you put Future objects in the sink.